# Can confirm service is running but can not check it's status

Tags: linux, services

Service name is zabbix_agentd and OS : Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.09

When i type

```
service --status-all
```

I see  **zabbix_agentd (pid 10052)is running**

But when i type

```
service status zabbix_agentd
```

I get : **zabbix_agentd: unrecognized service**

Why my service is not recognized even though I can confirm it on running services ?

Comment: What OS are you using ?

Comment: Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.09

Answer (score 1):

This is `service` command usage:

```
[root@server ~]# service --help
Usage: service < option > | --status-all | [ service_name [ command | --full-restart ] ]
```

It should be:

```
service zabbix_agentd status
```

not:

```
service status zabbix_agentd
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this works like this:

```
ls /etc/init.d
```

This shows me 'zabbix-agent' (without 'd' at the end),
by doing:

```
sudo service zabbix-agent status
```

I get 'zabbix_agentd (pid  4529) is running...' (tried also with start, stop, restart)